# On a 12 V car alternator with possible failure of the rectifier diode causing drainage, could an electronic component be added in-line near battery?

Tags: diodes, voltage-regulator, automotive, rectifier, alternator

On a 12 V car alternator with possible failure of the rectifier diode/s causing drainage, could an electronic component be added in-line near the battery? Such as a voltage regulator or diodes in line from the alternator.

Comment: A diode, but it would need to rated for as high current as the alternator could deliver, cooling of it and reduced battery voltage. Easier and cheaper to just repair the alternator.

Answer (score 1):

If one diode in a full wave rectifier failed, one of two things can happen: -

- One phase of the alternator fails to deliver any energy (open circuit diode)
- One phase of the alternator is shorted each half cycle (short circuit failure)

> *could an electronic component be added in-line near the battery?*

It would neither recover the energy lost in scenario 1 nor be able to stop the short circuit in scenario 2.

Answer (score 1):

Such kind of failures tend to evolve further. Don't consider the new status quo as long term stable operating condition. A bunch of power schottky diodes in parallel can let you limp home, but the alternator windings also may burn sooner or later and everything get worse.